# Complejidad algorítmica de matrices Strassen vs multiplicación tradicional

Tags: python, algoritmos, matrices, complejidad

Estoy implementando en Python un programa por consola que multiplique 2 matrices cuadradas de orden potencia de 2 n=(2,4,8,16,32,64,...) utilizando la [multiplicación de matrices iterativa](https://gist.github.com/parzibyte/bb96d0c5089858b3de2110ec208f55a5#file-producto-py) (la forma tradicional) de complejidad O(N* *3) y el [Algoritmo de Strassen](https://github.com/stanislavkozlovski/Algorithms/blob/master/Coursera/algorithms_stanford/Strassen%20Matrix%20Multiplication/python/strassen.py) de complejidad O(N* *2.83). Mi problema esta en que después de generar 2 matrices aleatorias de orden n, y tomar los tiempos de ambas multiplicaciones (forma tradicional y Strassen) con dichas matrices generadas, el tiempo de multiplicación mediante la forma tradicional es mucho mejor al tiempo del algoritmo de Strassen, pensé en que el repositorio usado no era el correcto por lo que busque otros códigos de multiplicación de Strassen en github y tengo la sorpresa de que la forma tradicional en tiempo es mucho mejor, lo cual no se refleja en la notación asintótica.
Espero la explicación a esto, de ante mano muchas gracias.
Como implemente [el código](https://gist.github.com/Stormlocc/840c7d2ec87af85e6a49163f771fa2cd).

```
import random
import time


#El siguiente Algoritmo de Strassen es sacado de
#https://github.com/stanislavkozlovski/Algorithms/blob/master/Coursera/algorithms_stanford/Strassen%20Matrix%20Multiplication/python/strassen.py

def default_matrix_multiplication(a, b):
    """
    Only for 2x2 matrices
    """
    if len(a) != 2 or len(a[0]) != 2 or len(b) != 2 or len(b[0]) != 2:
        raise Exception('Matrices should be 2x2!')
    #print(a[0][0] * b[0][1] + a[0][1] * b[1][1])
    new_matrix = [[a[0][0] * b[0][0] + a[0][1] * b[1][0], a[0][0] * b[0][1] + a[0][1] * b[1][1]],
                  [a[1][0] * b[0][0] + a[1][1] * b[1][0], a[1][0] * b[0][1] + a[1][1] * b[1][1]]]

    return new_matrix


def matrix_addition(matrix_a, matrix_b):
    # print(matrix_a)
    return [[matrix_a[row][col] + matrix_b[row][col]
             for col in range(len(matrix_a[row]))] for row in range(len(matrix_a))]


def matrix_subtraction(matrix_a, matrix_b):
    return [[matrix_a[row][col] - matrix_b[row][col]
             for col in range(len(matrix_a[row]))] for row in range(len(matrix_a))]


def split_matrix(a):
    """
    Given a matrix, return the TOP_LEFT, TOP_RIGHT, BOT_LEFT and BOT_RIGHT quadrant
    """
    if len(a) % 2 != 0 or len(a[0]) % 2 != 0:
        raise Exception('Odd matrices are not supported!')

    matrix_length = len(a)
    mid = matrix_length // 2
    top_left = [[a[i][j] for j in range(mid)] for i in range(mid)]
    bot_left = [[a[i][j] for j in range(mid)] for i in range(mid, matrix_length)]

    top_right = [[a[i][j] for j in range(mid, matrix_length)] for i in range(mid)]
    bot_right = [[a[i][j] for j in range(mid, matrix_length)] for i in range(mid, matrix_length)]

    return top_left, top_right, bot_left, bot_right


def get_matrix_dimensions(matrix):
    return len(matrix), len(matrix[0])


def strassen(matrix_a, matrix_b):
    """
    Recursive function to calculate the product of two matrices, using the Strassen Algorithm.
    Currently only works for matrices of even length (2x2, 4x4, 6x6...etc)
    """
    if get_matrix_dimensions(matrix_a) != get_matrix_dimensions(matrix_b):
        raise Exception(f'Both matrices are not the same dimension! \nMatrix A:{matrix_a} \nMatrix B:{matrix_b}')
    if get_matrix_dimensions(matrix_a) == (2, 2):
        return default_matrix_multiplication(matrix_a, matrix_b)

    A, B, C, D = split_matrix(matrix_a)
    E, F, G, H = split_matrix(matrix_b)

    p1 = strassen(A, matrix_subtraction(F, H))
    p2 = strassen(matrix_addition(A, B), H)
    p3 = strassen(matrix_addition(C, D), E)
    p4 = strassen(D, matrix_subtraction(G, E))
    p5 = strassen(matrix_addition(A, D), matrix_addition(E, H))
    p6 = strassen(matrix_subtraction(B, D), matrix_addition(G, H))
    p7 = strassen(matrix_subtraction(A, C), matrix_addition(E, F))

    top_left = matrix_addition(matrix_subtraction(matrix_addition(p5, p4), p2), p6)
    top_right = matrix_addition(p1, p2)
    bot_left = matrix_addition(p3, p4)
    bot_right = matrix_subtraction(matrix_subtraction(matrix_addition(p1, p5), p3), p7)

    # construct the new matrix from our 4 quadrants
    new_matrix = []
    for i in range(len(top_right)):
        new_matrix.append(top_left[i] + top_right[i])
    for i in range(len(bot_right)):
        new_matrix.append(bot_left[i] + bot_right[i])
    return new_matrix

#Fin de algoritmo de Strassen



#Funciones adicionales para generar matriz aleatoria
def generateMat(f, c):
    M = []
    for i in range(f):
        M.append([])
        for j in range(c):
            M[i].append(random.randint(0,10))
    return M

#Funcion adicional para mostrar la matriz
def mostrarMat(M):
    print("\n")
    for fila in M:
        print(fila)
    print("\n")

# Algoritmo de multiplicacion de matrices de forma iterativa
#https://gist.github.com/parzibyte/bb96d0c5089858b3de2110ec208f55a5#file-producto-py

def producto_matrices(a, b):
    filas_a = len(a)
    filas_b = len(b)
    columnas_a = len(a[0])
    columnas_b = len(b[0])
    if columnas_a != filas_b:
        return None
    # Asignar espacio al producto. Es decir, rellenar con "espacios vacíos"
    producto = []
    for i in range(filas_b):
        producto.append([])
        for j in range(columnas_b):
            producto[i].append(None)
    # Rellenar el producto
    for c in range(columnas_b):
        for i in range(filas_a):
            suma = 0
            for j in range(columnas_a):
                suma += a[i][j]*b[j][c]
            producto[i][c] = suma
    return producto

#Fin de algoritmo de producto de 2 matrices

#_________________________________________________________________________
print("    Programa que multiplica 2 matrices    ")
orden = int(input("Generar orden: "))

A = generateMat(orden,orden)
B = generateMat(orden,orden)

mostrarMat(A)
mostrarMat(B)

print("Strassen")
inicio = time.time()
C = strassen(A,B)
fin = time.time()
mostrarMat(C)
tStrassen = fin -inicio

print("Tradicional")
inicio = time.time()
D= producto_matrices(A,B)
fin = time.time()
mostrarMat(D)
tTradicional = fin -inicio
print("Tiempo de strassen: " , tStrassen)
print("Tiempo de normal: " , tTradicional)
```

Comment: lo que pedis es interesante.. pero no se te puede decir un porque sin ver si los algoritmos son correctos y sus implementaciones son perfectas. Ademas, vos estas comparando algoritmos sobre lenguajes interpretados, con lo cual puede que el interprete maneje algunas secciones del codigo de formas no muy eficientes. Estas comparaciones deberias hacerlas sobre lenguajes compilados....

Comment: @gbianchi , actualice la pregunta, donde ahora incluyo los algoritmos.

Comment: La _complejidad algorítmica_ no va de comparar velocidades, sino de ver cómo es capaz de _"escalar"_ un algoritmo. Aunque ahora veas mejores tiempos con la multiplicación tradicional, según vayas incrementando el número de elementos en varios órdenes deberías empezar a observar cómo mejora el de _Strassen_.

Comment: El codigo debe estar en la pregunta... Chema tiene razon en su comentario.. ademas, vos deberias probarlo no con una matriz.. si no con cientos (o miles) de matrices sucesivas en el tiempo... no basta con solo una corrida de ejemplo... el tiempo se calcula en base a ejecutar el mismo codigo miles de veces, y calcular el promedio de tiempo de los mismos....

Comment: Ya probé con matrices de orden 1024 y 2048 y tengo el mismo resultado, si el algoritmo de Strassen "escala mejor" a partir de que orden? por que solo en python?